# .bat searching for a file that could be in different file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch file that if the program exists then it ends. but if it doesn't exist it'll begin installing that program.

When the program installs, there is a part in the file path with 4 random numbers it creates and resides in. I'm unsure if my script will look through this or not. So far I've created:

```
@echo off 
REM === Agent already deployed on the computer? 
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Remote Support Customer\????\g2ax_comm_customer.*" goto END 
REM === Deploying agent in silent mode 
"\\location.exe" --mode unattended 
REM === Script done 
:END
```

I know the install works so I left that out. I don't do a lot with Windows command prompt and unsure if my if exist will work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "supportdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Remote Support Customer"

REM === Agent already deployed on the computer?
for /d %%A in ("%supportdir%\*") do if exist "%%~A\g2ax_comm_customer.*" exit /b
REM === Deploying agent in silent mode
"\\location.exe" --mode unattended
```

The `????` path segment will not be resolved so you may need to iterate
the unknown sub-directories using a `for /d` loop. Wildcards are valid for the last segment.

The `%%~A` will have the absolute paths of what used to be `????`.
Now is possible to test if `%%~A\g2ax_comm_customer.*` does exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply recursively search the parent directory.

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Remote Support Customer" %i in (g2ax_comm_customer.*) do if not exist %%i "\\location.exe" --mode unattended
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir` is able to search in subfolders with the `/s` switch. Redirect it's output to NUL and use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) on success/fail:

```
dir /s /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Remote Support Customer\g2ax_comm_customer.*"  >nul 2>&1 && (
  echo found the file
) || (
  echo didn't find the file
)
```